# Is it possible to include multiple templates into a docusign envelope based on sfdc fields?

Tags: docusignapi, apex, sfdc

We use up to three supplemental forms that we'd like to send in addition to the main agreement. Ideally I'd like to deploy three check boxes so the user can choose to add all three or one or none of the additional forms. If a box is checked then that form would be included in the envelope.

Answer (score 2):

Not through the standard/default DocuSign setup.

You can write some Apax logic as part of a custom button to do this.

Other option would be just to create a master template with anchor text,
then place anchor text to whatever relevant anchor fields you want on the document you are sending and only those will be brought over from the master template.

Comment: I'm using apex. The flow already is looking at a field to determine which of 5 templates to use. What I'm hoping is that I can add a few if statements associated with additional templates associated to those if's being true-

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing your docusign template id between the if else conditions like this:

```
Pagereference pg = Page.dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope;
String DST = DSTValue;

if(your condition){
//change tempalte id here DST = abc;
} else {
 DST = pqr;
}

pg.getParameters().put('DST',DST); 


return String.valueOf(pg.getUrl());
```